# Magento 2 : What template engine is used for email templates?

Tags: magento2, template, email-templates

What template engine is used for `Magento2`'s **email templates**? I've not been able to get confirmation on this.

Comment: Did you find an answer for that ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, they still use a custom template "engine" developed by [varien inc. which originally developed magento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento#History).

You can see how it works in the magento sources: https://github.com/inviqa/magento-community/blob/master/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php